# Reset_cooldown Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im pretty new to discord.py, and python in general but im trying to learn. I dont know how to add the command.reset_cooldown to my code. As it says in the code below, i want !test to ignore the cooldown but i want !test 2 to have the cooldown. Can someone help me?

````
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx, command=None):
    if command is None:
        await ctx.send('I want this to ignore cooldown')
    elif command.lower() == '2':
        await ctx.send('I want this to have a Cooldown')```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx, command=None):
    if command is None:
        await ctx.send('I want this to ignore cooldown')
        test.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    elif command.lower() == '2':
        await ctx.send('I want this to have a Cooldown')
```

Essentially, exactly what the guy above said, but without the `await`. Tried the his code and it didn't work, luckily I was able to find sources that pointed me in the right directions.

Answer (score 2):

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx, command=None):
    if command is None:
        await ctx.send('I want this to ignore cooldown')
        test.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    elif command.lower() == '2':
        await ctx.send('I want this to have a Cooldown')
```

`await test.reset_cooldown(ctx)` will reset the cooldown for the user that invoked the command.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx, command=None):
    if command is None:
        await ctx.send('I want this to ignore cooldown')
        ctx.command.reset_cooldown(ctx)  
        # reset_cooldown is an attribute of `Command`, not `function`

    elif command.lower() == '2':
        await ctx.send('I want this to have a Cooldown')
```

For future reference and new readers, the Discord.py Extensions (discord.etx) do this differently and is stated in the 1.4 documentary. 
Instead of calling `reset_cooldown` on the function, you call it on the `Command` object, which is from `Context` (`ctx.command`).
Source: [discord.ext.commands.Command.reset_cooldown](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=reset_cooldown#discord.ext.commands.Command.reset_cooldown) 
I had to find this out myself too, since my cooldown function returns at points where a cooldown of five minutes is not deserved.