# Discord.py interaction slash command cooldowns

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a lottery bot and one of the functions is to only let people play the lottery once every 2 hours. To achieve this, I'm using `app_commands.checks.cooldown` : [cool down documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands%20checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown)

It all works as expected however there is certain circumstances where I would like to skip over the cool down and I can't seem to reset it. here's my snippet.

```
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 7200, key=lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=1002036221725388900), name="test", description="testing")
    async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    lotterychannel = bot.get_channel(1002055003491545099)
    if interaction.channel.id != 1002055003491545099:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**Ops!!**", description=f"The lottery can only be played in <#1002696404046712932>!", color=0x00ff00)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        test.remove_check() #place remove cool down here
    else:
        #other code
```

I have looked through the documentation and I cant find a way to remove the cool down. I would guess it has something to do with lambda.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can try this [`reset()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands%20checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.Cooldown.reset)

Comment: Thanks, I did try this before posting with no luck. :/. I appreciate the response.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60291085/17067135) can help you . It did works for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. Ill look into this method and see if it would be ideal to switch.

Comment: Maybe you can create a decorator to cooldown the command manually. I also recommended you to use [nextcord](https://nextcord.dev), a well-maintained discord bot module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Development team of Discord.py

"there currently isn't a way to reset the cooldown
you would have to make your own cooldown check if you want to reset it"